# How can I retrieve a file that I saved on a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Here's my current code:

```
MySqlConnection.Open()
command.Connection = MySqlConnection
command.CommandText = "select * from add_document"

READER = command.ExecuteReader
READER.Read()

Dim filebytes() As Byte = CType(READER(1), Byte())

Dim FStream As New FileStream(READER(0).ToString, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
FStream.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length)
FStream.Close()

MessageBox.Show("File Retrieved")
```

I am receiving the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type'system.string' to type 'system.byte[]

Comment: What is the code you used to save the file in the database?

Comment: Looks like `READER(1)` doesn't contain the column you expect it to.